# Aesthetic error while plotting multiple labels on x axis in histogram using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data in the below format

```
occupation,how_many_happy, how_many_not_happy  
Teacher, 50, 30
```

I am trying to plot a histogram by using both `how_many_happy`, `how_many_not_happy` on the x axis for each occupation separatly using ggplot as below

```
ggplot(Occupations_vs_parties,
       aes(x = c(Occupations_vs_parties$How_many_happy, 
                 Occupations_vs_parties$How_many_not_happy))) + 
       facet_wrap(~Occupation, nrow = 4)
```

However I am getting the error as below

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (17): x
```

Can you please help me with the way forward. Please let me know if any inputs are needed

Thanks,
Surya

Comment: There are fundamental `ggplot` syntax errors in your code that I didn't want to edit. Please see my example solution below.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few mistakes in your code. Most fundamentally, I would recommend reading up on (1) [converting data from wide to long format](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/), and (2) general `ggplot` syntax, especially the use of `geom_histogram` and `geom_bar` (for example you don't actually specify *how* you want to plot your data).

With the sample data that you give, there is also no point in facet wrapping `occupation`. So your example data might not be a representative minimal example.

Here is an simple barplot based on your sample data.

```
# Sample data
df <- read.csv(text =
    "occupation,how_many_happy,how_many_not_happy
    Teacher,50,30", sep = ",");

# Convert wide to long dataframe
library(reshape2);
df.long <- melt(df);

# (gg)plot
require(ggplot2);
ggplot(df.long, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity"),
```

[image]

If you do have different `occupation` levels, you can add `... + facet_wrap(~ occuptation)` to your `ggplot` command.